# Extjs how to load multiple resources at once

Tags: extjs, promise, resources

Normally I use javascript promises in order to load my resources, and in order to load resources simultaneosly I use `Promise.all`, but I'm trying to learn Extjs and I want to know if there is a way to load multiple resources at once, like in `Promise.all`, if so, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `Ext.data.Connection` class. This is a wrapper to asynchronous AJAX calls.